# Please explain the following code

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

```
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_customer.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';
```

Comment: Which API you are trying to call ? 
Can you please describe that  ?

Comment: I am trying to call REST API .
Actually i am getting error : HTTP ERROR 500